# set value of input programatically doesn't refresh component DOM

Tags: vue.js

I have an input which is bidden to property message. I have a set button , which I use for changing of input value programmatically. When the button is pressed, value of input is correctly changed to `'xxxx'`. when I press clean button after that , the input is correctly cleaned but when I repeat pressing set and clean again the input does not get cleared anymore.

Working example is here:

https://codepen.io/dan-ouek/pen/rNBjxRO

```
<div class="container">
  <div id='root' class="box">
    <input ref="templateFilter" type='text' id='input' v-model='message'>
    {{ message }}
    <button @click="set">set</button>
    <button @click="clean">clean</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue'
  },
  methods: {
    set: function () {
       let element = this.$refs.templateFilter
       Vue.set(element, 'value', 'xxxx')
  }, clean: function () {
      this.message = ""
  }
}})
```

**Questions:**

1) Is it possible to change input programmatically without working with bidden property value? Something like direct DOM manipulation:

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("templateFilter")[0]
element.value = 'xxxxx'
```

but with proper component refresh?

2) Why is the `{{ message }}` not refreshed after calling set method?

Comment: why not just `this.message = "xxxx"` inside the set method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is the `message` not refreshed after calling set method?**

When you type something on your input the `message` data gets updated via an event handler BUT when you set it programmatically the event handler is NOT triggered and that's why `message` was not getting updated / refreshed....

**Solution :**

a short solution to your issue would be just to mutate the `message` value `this.message = "xxxx"` but if you insist on making that programmatically  you have to trigger the input event :

```js
set: function() {
  let element = this.$refs.templateFilter
  Vue.set(element, 'value', 'xxxx')
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
}
```

Here is a Demo : [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/MWgJXZb?editors=1111)